# Calling JavaScript Method From UIwebView . (JS method is in Native Bridge)

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, iphone

I have tried most of the ways of calling JS method using Objective-C , have searched stackOverflow for this as well, but nothing was helpful .

My question is .
I am receiving a html link in API response that I am showing in UIWebView.
The html is as below

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//static.cardekho.com/javascript/cardekhoFTC.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

The JS method that I need to call is written in this link "//static.cardekho.com/javascript/cardekhoFTC.js"

I have tried calling this by standard method.

```
[self.myWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"toggleHotspotOff()"];
```

But it doesn't help .

I am new to JS interaction with iOS .

It is something to do with nativeBridge I suppose .
Thanks in advance.
Let me know if I missed anything to make my question clear .

Comment: Where you calling `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` method of `UIWebView` ?

Comment: webview delegate method didfinishLoad

Comment: did you find solution?